# Cannot find module error while using Node.js and running npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am not able to run the command `npm install -g@iconic/cli` or any NPM command, thou when I check for NPM version it is coming up.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: There should be a space between `-g` and the name of the package. Isn't this causing the problem?